# Sample Kii Cloud code for Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, paas, kiicloud

I'm testing Kii Cloud's Unity SDK and I'm in desperate need for a sample. I'm trying to use the user management feature. A user registration form takes user data and I call Kii Cloud user registration API. I get an exception when calling user.Register(password) with little useful data (but it looks like it could be a connectivity issue):

```
KiiCorp.Cloud.Storage.NetworkException: network related exception ---> System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure
```

Could anybody provide a user registration sample for Kii Cloud in Unity? Anybody had issues registering users?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which platform are you building for when getting the exception? If you're on web player try to switch to native win/mac. The problem might be related to the lack of network access in a sandboxed environment.

With regards to samples check these two:

https://github.com/KiiPlatform/KiiUnitySDKSamples

https://github.com/KiiPlatform/UnityAngryBotsKii

Happy coding!

Comment: I changed to Win/Mac and now it works. The web player target is the one causing this exception. I'm still not sure why but I can live with running under win/mac platform for testing purposes. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Do you have internet connection in your environment?
I have tried to implement using examples from offical document.
It works for me.

http://documentation.kii.com/en/guides/unity/managing-users/sign-up/

Answer (score 1):

The cause is connectivity issue as you guessed.
Which version of SDK are you using? Until v1.2.0 you need to add trusted root on your side.
(If you are using latest (v1.3.0) no need to add trusted root on your side.)
And did you tested to connect other apis without using Kii SDK in your environment?

As for samples, unfortunately I could not find but there's some snippets in here
http://documentation.kii.com/en/guides/unity/managing-users/sign-up/

Comment: Thanks Satoshi. I switched platform and now it works. The problem only happens with the web player.